# My Excel "Run-Time error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

I get the

> Run-Time error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set

when I open my program from a cloud storage location, and it opens with the warning question "   "enable contents".  When I click Enable the error 91 appears.  If I open from my computer there is not problem.  I do need to be able to download and open from the cloud storage location. My code is below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 With ActiveSheet
    .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    If Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    Range("A" & Target.Row, "J" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: a) Which line produces the error? b) Change `With ActiveSheet` into `With Me` and also specify `Me` for the `Range` like `Me.Range`.

Comment: The error occurs on line 4  " .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone"

Comment: Even after the changes I suggested?

Comment: I replaced With Activesheet with With Me.  Added Me.Range after With Me and received a Compile Error at .Range???? Changed to Me.Range("A" & Target.Row, "J" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 27.   It seems to work correctly.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: wrote it as an answer so you can accept it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `With ActiveSheet` into `With Me` and also specify `Me` for the `Range` like `Me.Range` (or make it use the with statement and start it with a dot like `.Range`).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With Me
        .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        If Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
             .Range("A" & Target.Row, "J" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End If
    End With    
End Sub
```

**Why is this an important difference?**

`ActiveSheet` is the sheet that has the focus (is on top) at the moment the code runs. But this is not necessarily the sheet that triggered the event or `Target` is in. Therfore you try to change the color of different sheet. Avoid using `ActiveSheet` at any cost. In most cases it is not needed (unless in rare cases eg if you write an addin or something similar).

You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) which is about a very similar topic.